How to subscribe to volume events?
I'm trying to subscribe to Alsa volume events, but the callback is not being called.
Alsa.PcmDevice defCard;
Alsa.PcmDevice.open(out defCard, "hw:1", Alsa.PcmStream.PLAYBACK, 0);
int n_fds = defCard.get_poll_descriptors_count();
Posix.pollfd[] fds = new Posix.pollfd[n_fds];

channels = new IOChannel[n_fds];
watches = new uint[n_fds];

defCard.set_poll_descriptors(fds);
for (var i = 0; i < n_fds; ++i)
{
  var channel = new IOChannel.unix_new(fds[i].fd);
  watches[i] = channel.add_watch(IOCondition.IN, asound_mixer_event);
  channels[i] = channel;
}

It seems to somewhat work because I'm getting a lot of events with IOCondition.OUT and IOCondition.ERR but nothing on IOCondition.IN which I think I need for volume events. What am I missing here?
Figured it out. For the one guy who might need this in the future, first of all this is almost certainly not how you're "supposed" to do it, but at this point IDGAF. So what I did was googled "alsa.vapi" copied it to my project, then added:
vapi_dir = meson.current_source_dir()
add_project_arguments(['--vapidir', vapi_dir], language: 'vala')
dependencies = [
    dependency('alsa'),
    meson.get_compiler('vala').find_library('posix'),
]

to my meson.build file (the last line with posix is important, without it there were errors). Then I edited my copy of alsa.vapi and added following lines:
public int poll_descriptors_count ();
public int poll_descriptors (Posix.pollfd[] pfds);
public int handle_events ();

to snd_mixer_t compact class, then I used this code to register events:
Alsa.Mixer mixer;
uint[] watches;
IOChannel[] channels;
Alsa.Mixer.open(out mixer, 0);
mixer.attach();
mixer.register();
mixer.load();
int n_fds = mixer.poll_descriptors_count();
Posix.pollfd[] fds = new Posix.pollfd[n_fds];
channels = new IOChannel[n_fds];
watches = new uint[n_fds];
mixer.poll_descriptors(fds);
for (var i = 0; i < n_fds; ++i)
{
  var channel = new IOChannel.unix_new(fds[i].fd);
  watches[i] = channel.add_watch(IOCondition.IN, asound_mixer_event);
  channels[i] = channel;
}

and finally in asound_mixer_event callback added:
mixer.handle_events();

